# javascript:history.go(-1) not working with IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript

I am trying the below code for traversing back to the previous page and it does not work on IE and Chrome but works fine on Edge.

```
<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)" class="back" >
            <asp:Label ID="backLabel" runat="server" Text="Back" meta:resourcekey="backLabelResource1" />
        </a>
```

Also tried this as per some threads I read

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="history.back(); return false;" class="back" >
            <asp:Label ID="backLabel" runat="server" Text="Back" meta:resourcekey="backLabelResource1" />
        </a>
```

Still same result.
Any ideas?

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="history..go(-1); return false;" class="back" >
            <asp:Label ID="backLabel" runat="server" Text="Back" meta:resourcekey="backLabelResource1" />
        </a>
will not work either

Comment: When you say "does not work" - do you see anything happening? Any errors in the console?  Is there definitely a page to navigate back to?

Comment: webpage has expired on IE

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with `history.go` as both Chrome and IE [support it](https://caniuse.com/#feat=history). This code does work:

```js
document.getElementById("mylink").addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("Hello world!")
    // Or alternatively:
    //history.go(-1);
});
```

```html
<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Navigate 1 page backwards</a>
<br /><br />

<a href="javascript:alert('Hello World!')">Announce "Hello World"</a>
<br /><br />

<a href="javascript:alert('Hello World!')">
  <label>This is a label wrapped in an a tag which is not recommended, and will not work on certain browsers such as IE (and for example in this specific case does not show the pointer cursor in Chrome)</label>
</a>
<br /><br />

<label>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="mylink">
    This is correct practice. No inline js, and the a tag is in the label tag and not the other way around (which only matters if you want to work with IE as other modern browsers allow this).
</a>
</label>
```

The above works for me using Chrome 66 (latest). Perhaps try and see what ASP renders in the browser using inspect element and check if some of the code may be invalid. All the above solutions should work.

---

Also, it is considered bad practice to use inline js. **Read more:**

- [Is inline JavaScript good or bad?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61731/is-inline-javascript-good-or-bad/61741)
- [Why Inline CSS And JavaScript Code Is Such A Bad Thing](https://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/)
- [Reddit - why is inline onclick="function()" considered such a bad practice?](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/3kamqn/why_is_inline_onclickfunction_considered_such_a/)

Comment: Could it be bcoz I have the anchor tag in div tag?

Comment: No. That shouldn't matter at all. It's perfectly normal to have an anchor in a div - but specifically the anchor tag shouldn't contain other tags, even though it's possible in modern browsers. I suggest learning HTML and JS better for your better understanding what's going on. *Perhaps try and see what ASP renders in the browser using inspect element and check if some of the code may be invalid.*

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
window.history.back()
```

or

```
window.history.forward()
```

Reference 'Traveling through history':  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API